# HTML button Activity using AppScript/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking to pass data to a Google Spreadsheet based on a button activity such as 'Yes', 'No', so we can see if the article is useful or not.

Would this be JavaScript or is it all AppScript? I'm not sure where to start and was hoping for some hints. Below is what I would like to pass to the Google Spreadsheet.

1. URL,
2. Yes, or No based on the activity of the button

[image: Image Attached - Click link here]

Answer (score 1):

Just use Google Sheets to save into a database using AJAX:

### Examples

**appscript:** https://mashe.hawksey.info/2014/07/google-sheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-using-postget-methods-with-ajax-example/

**javascript:** http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/721795/Store-your-form-data-in-Google-Spreadsheet

Both links store user-entered data in google sheets.

Comment: This is a great start. Thank you for sharing the links. I will give them a try.

Comment: Thanks !.. You can...!

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).